# Hellosign- Prevent loading default email message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using HelloSign for document signatures in my Project.
I have created a template and sending the same to users for signatures.
Also I can set message and title. But is there a way to remove the text that says HelloSign account owner has requested for a signature and other messages and templates that comes by default..apart from the messages and title we set via code.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to customize this text for these kinds of signature requests.

One alternative:

If you ever decide to have the signers of your signature requests sign directly on your site (instead of hellosign.com), check out HelloSign's  Embedded Signing feature. When a signature request is made for embedded signing, HelloSign does not send ANY emails and requires you to send those instead (making them infinitely customizable :).